# How to create an automatically reconnect webSocket class extends WebSocket in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We can have a function to implement the reconnect. I know can just modify the close function, eg.

```
let ws = new WebSocket(uri);
ws.onclose = () => {
  ws = new WebSocket(uri);
}
```

but what if I want to use a class?

```
class AutoWebSocket extends WebSocket {
  constructor(uri, protocols) {
   super(uri, protocols);
  }
  onclose() {
    this = new AutoWebSocket(uri, protocols);
  }
}
```

I got error with:

> Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reassign `this`, you can only read from it, therefore it is invalid on the left-hand side of an expression.

If you need to recreate the socket, use composition, not inheritance:

```
 class AuoWebSocket {
   constructor(uri, protocols) {
     this.uri = uri; this.protocols = protocols;
     this.init();         
   }

   init() {
      this.socket = new WebSocket(uri, protocols);

      this.socket.onerror = () => {
        this.init();
      };
   }
 }
```